# Как сделать Checkbox? если (checkbox) выставлен то включить фильтр по полю

Tags: php, form, checkbox, фильтры

Как сделать, чтобы если (checkbox) выставлен то включить фильтр по полю `sport_id` и выводились только те строки где в поле `sport_id` стоит '1'. БД Oracle

```
<form action=" " method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="sport_id" value="1">
</form>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <p></p>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <?php 
            echo form_checkbox(
                'sport_id', sport::checkboxValid(), 
                ($this->input->get('sport_id') > 0) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') 
        ?>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110389/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-checkbox

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать Checkbox?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110389/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-checkbox)